# firebase persistance in React, user loggedOut on every page reload

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a very serious issue with Firebase Authentication State Persistence, when using a single page web app I was able to access `firebase.auth()` until explicit logOut, right now on every reload I got undefined and the user is loggedOut, I am using this for navigation:

```
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={DefaultLayout} />
      {this.state.loggedOut ? <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Login} /> : null }
      {this.state.loggedIn ? <Route path="/" name="Home" component={DefaultLayout} /> : null }          
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
```

So when I login and move to the dashboard I use that function:

```
  login(e) {
    this.setState({ loading:true });
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u)=>{
      this.setState({ loading:false, loggedIn: true });
      localStorage.setItem('AuthStatut', this.state.loggedIn);
      window.location.hash = "#/Dashboard";
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Everything is working on dashboard on first try, to see what's going on I use this on Dashboard.js

```
   componentDidMount() {
     const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
     this.setState({ fullname:  currentUser ? currentUser.displayName : 'TEST'  })
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.state.fullname}</p>

   ...
```

When I reload the page the user is loggedOut and got fullname: TEST

I have no idea why this is happening. Please someone help

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify persistance on login.

From docs:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(function() {
    // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
    // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
    // if a user forgets to sign out.
    // ...
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

Comment: Okay, I thought it was pretty obvious. Just put your `firebase.auth().signIn....` inside the `.then()` function on `firebase.auth().setPersistence()`